# Is there an easy way to get rid of all these edges?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I made this belt out of a path, but it came out with too many edges (the horizontal ones).

Just wondering, is there a way to get rid of most of those edges in one fell swoop?

[image: belt]

Comment: Select one of them, then `Select -> Select Similar -> Length` then `ctrl x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the ring of edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Right Click</kbd>:

[image]

Then *Select > Checker Deselect* to select one edge out of two (or choose the ratio in the *Operator Box*):

[image]

Then *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops* in order to select the edge loops all around, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve:

[image]